# LSTM shape error when predicting stock prices

Tags: python, tensorflow

Im following a tutorial on how to predict stock prices with tensor flow.
but everytime i run my script i keep getting a shape error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 38, in <module>
    model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I know here on stackoverflow are some similiar answers to this question but to be honest im new to ML so i cant make much sense of the answers given.

The full code is here:
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/c4mDKNF3hp/

Comment: is `x_train` a `list` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input to the neural network must be a numpy array. It seems like you are trying to input a python list.
To convert the list into a numpy array do this:

```
nparray = np.array(python_list)
```

Do it with both inputs and answers. (x_train and y_train). In your code you are only converting the test data to a numpy array.

It is giving an error because x_train.shape[1] doesn't exist. Python lists don't have a "shape" attribute, numpy arrays do.